# Signing / Initialling multple pages - multple signers

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

We've implemented DocuSign in our e-Builder instance.  It works okay on normal documents with the normal signing actions.  We would now like to sign our CAD plans in a similar fashion.  Some plans sets have over 100 pages.  Each page needs to be initialed, signed, and stamped.  So, placing all the signature "Tabs" is a bit time consuming.  When the signer receives the plans, all of these should be positioned already right where we want them.  Same x,y on each sheet.

What would be the best approach to placing these?  Python?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: are you writing code? cause you can automate all of this with the API, but your question suggests maybe you are using UI only?

Comment: I was under the impression I would need to write some code.  The Rest API perhaps?  And to keep it simple I was hoping to use Python if possible.  Do you think that is a workable solution?  Otherwise I have VS 2017, which I think is more complicated than this solution needs to be.  Thank you for responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either Python or C# (with VS 2017) to use the REST API and it has the functionality you want.
Here is some code example to help you:
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/set-envelope-tab-values

GitHub Python code can be found here:
https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-python-auth-code-grant/blob/master/app/eg016_set_tab_values.py

GitHub C# code can be found here:
https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/blob/master/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/Controllers/Eg016SetTabValues.cs

You will need to get a sandbox/demo account and get an integration key to make API calls.